# SSL_CERT_DIR and SSL_CERT_FILE openssl env variable on Linux

Tags: ssl, openssl, miniconda

My Linux box has certificate in /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

I have installed miniconda and tried to use its urllib.request package.

```
import urllib.request
r = urllib.request("https://example.com")
```

according to openssl documentation, ca-bundle.crt file should be picked by openssl if i set the SSL_CERT_DIR to "/etc/pki/tls/certs".
but instead i get error
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED].

when i set the variable SSL_CERT_FILE to "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt" everything works fine.

why setting the SSl_CERT_DIR did not worked ? according to documentation it should work.

Comment: It is unclear what the contents of the directory and the file actually is and if the directory is even in the right format (i.e. names of entries based on subject hash). If the necessary CA is not in the directory or not in the right format it will simply not work.

Comment: content of the directory is following

lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   245832 Feb 14  2020 ca-bundle.crt 
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   293223 Feb 14  2020 ca-bundle.trust.crt

if i set the SSL_CERT_FILE to ca-bundle.crt present in the directory everything works fine.

what use SSL_CERT_DIR has ?

Comment: It looks like the contents of the directory is not the expected one. See the description of option `-CApath` in [openssl verify](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-verify.html) on how the directory structure and contents must be in order to be usable.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of the *SSL_CERT_DIR* environment variable is correct. The directory that is specified in the variable is meant for trusted root certificates (but not for intermediate ones!).

When copying the root certificates over to this directory, they have to follow a certain naming convention. The certificate should be in the regular PEM format, but the file name must be named

```
[HASH].0
```

where **[HASH]** is the hashed value of the certificate's subject. You can find out this hash value with the following command (replace root.cer with the file name of your root certificate)

```
openssl x509 -subject_hash -in root.cer
```

Disclaimer: I tested this on a Windows machine with openssl compiled for Windows. I did not have to create a symlink as mentioned in the manpage for *openssl verify*.