# Github action maven run

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have my workflow file below. It's currently running on self hosted local machine (Mac).

```
name: Maven Package

on:
  push:
    branches: ["test"]
  pull_request:
    branches: ["test"]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: [ self-hosted ]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        java-package: jdk
        distribution: 'zulu'

    - run: clean install
```

The JDK setup step of the job fails with this error:

> Trying to resolve the latest version from remote
> Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

How can I can resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by a proxy server between the machine that runs the self-hosted agent and the outside world.

You probably need to configure the OpenSSL certificate store on your agent to include the root certificates for your organization.

GitHub actions runners may run all kinds of tools that may need configuration in this case.

- set the `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` environment variable for node
- [set the `SSL_CERT_DIR` environment variable for openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73949796/736079)
- [set the git config `http.sslCAInfo` or `http.sslCAPath` values or `GIT_SSL_CAINFO` or `GIT_SSL_CAPATH` environment variables](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.22.0#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpsslCAInfo)
- [add your certificates to the Java Trust store](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5871352/736079)
- [on windows you can try setting the git config to use `http.sslBacnkend=schannel`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpsslBackend)
- [fix the configuration of the agent process itself](https://github.com/actions/runner/blob/main/docs/checks/sslcert.md)

Welcome to the hell of corporate servers with self-signed certificates.